# appending an array to a list

Tags: python, arrays, image, append

I am taking images and turning them into arrays. I want to append the arrays into an empty list but when I do I get `array(arr)` added to my list before the start of each image. `arr` being the actual image array. I want to append only the `values` without the `string` or `()`

code:

```
DIR = 'predictions\\12288_cropped\\'
pred = "predictions"
files = os.listdir(DIR)
norm_images = []
def prepfiles():
    for file in files:    
        def prepare(filepath):
            img_size = 256
            img_array = pydicom.read_file(filepath)
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array.pixel_array, (img_size, img_size))
            arr = new_array.copy().astype(np.float)
            M = np.float(np.max(new_array))
            if M != 0:
                arr *= 1./M
                norm_images.append(arr)
            return arr.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
        prepare(DIR+file)
prepfiles()
print('normalized images', norm_images)
```

print:

```
normalized images [array([[-0.39198218, -0.37936154, -0.36228656, ..., -0.7423905 ,
        -0.7423905 , -0.7423905 ],
       [-0.38678545, -0.36154417, -0.32665182, ..., -0.7423905 ,
        -0.7423905 , -0.7423905 ],
       [-0.36377134, -0.33927246, -0.29101707, ..., -0.7423905 ,
        -0.7423905 , -0.7423905 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.03266518,  0.0311804 ,  0.04231626, ...,  0.16332591,
         0.16332591,  0.14105419],
       [ 0.02152932, -0.00445434,  0.04008909, ...,  0.16778025,
         0.16926503,  0.16703786],
       [ 0.02004454,  0.00890869,  0.05642168, ...,  0.1484781 ,
         0.16555308,  0.16184113]]), array([[-0.32047686, -0.31486676, -0.32328191, ..., -0.70126227,
        -0.70126227, -0.70126227],
       [-0.32398317, -0.30645161, -0.2973352 , ..., -0.70126227,
        -0.70126227, -0.70126227],
       [-0.30715288, -0.28681627, -0.27840112, ..., -0.70126227,
        -0.70126227, -0.70126227],
       ...,
       [ 0.02173913,  0.01192146,  0.00981767, ...,  0.09396914,
         0.07713885,  0.07293128],
       [ 0.00701262, -0.00350631,  0.03856942, ...,  0.11220196,
         0.09467041,  0.10869565],
       [ 0.00981767,  0.02173913,  0.07573633, ...,  0.11290323,
         0.1227209 ,  0.11991585]])]
```

desired output:

```
normalized images [[[-0.39198218, -0.37936154, -0.36228656, ..., -0.7423905 ,
            -0.7423905 , -0.7423905 ],
           [-0.38678545, -0.36154417, -0.32665182, ..., -0.7423905 ,
            -0.7423905 , -0.7423905 ],
           [-0.36377134, -0.33927246, -0.29101707, ..., -0.7423905 ,
            -0.7423905 , -0.7423905 ],
           ...,
           [ 0.03266518,  0.0311804 ,  0.04231626, ...,  0.16332591,
             0.16332591,  0.14105419],
           [ 0.02152932, -0.00445434,  0.04008909, ...,  0.16778025,
             0.16926503,  0.16703786],
           [ 0.02004454,  0.00890869,  0.05642168, ...,  0.1484781 ,
             0.16555308,  0.16184113]], [[-0.32047686, -0.31486676, -0.32328191, ..., -0.70126227,
            -0.70126227, -0.70126227],
           [-0.32398317, -0.30645161, -0.2973352 , ..., -0.70126227,
            -0.70126227, -0.70126227],
           [-0.30715288, -0.28681627, -0.27840112, ..., -0.70126227,
            -0.70126227, -0.70126227],
           ...,
           [ 0.02173913,  0.01192146,  0.00981767, ...,  0.09396914,
             0.07713885,  0.07293128],
           [ 0.00701262, -0.00350631,  0.03856942, ...,  0.11220196,
             0.09467041,  0.10869565],
           [ 0.00981767,  0.02173913,  0.07573633, ...,  0.11290323,
             0.1227209 ,  0.11991585]]]
```

Comment: I believe you only need to change norm_images.append(arr) to norm_images.append(list(arr))

Answer (score 0):

There is no "`string`" it is just the output format. If you want to change it into a list then just apply the `tolist()` function of np to your array before appending it:

```
norm_images.append(arr.tolist())
```

This should give you your desired output.